# The arithmetic types (in C++) are defined to cater to the peculiarities of various kinds of hardware

Tags: c++

I read this sentence, while reading the "C++ Primer Book". What exactly does this sentence mean? And what are examples of those various kinds of hardware? How were the arithmetic types designed to do that? (at least consideration that were made to achieve that).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Signed integer overflow being undefined behaviour is one example. The fact that a type like `int` can vary in size from 2 to 8 bytes is another.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The standard allows `int`s even outside of that range of sizes. If `CHAR_BIT` is `16` or more `int` can have a `sizeof` 1 ([example](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru514q/spru514q.pdf)). And since there is no maximum size requirement, `sizeof(int)` can be any integer greater than zero. More evidence that c++ is very accommodating of unusual hardware.

Comment: Edit : Technically the example I linked above is a c compiler, but the c++ has similar allowances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C and C++ a `char` has to be at least 8 bits wide. A `short` has to be at least 16 bits wide and at least as wide as a `char`. An `int` has to be at least 16 bits wide and at least as wide as a `short`. A `long` has to be at least 32 bits wide and at least as wide as an `int`. A `long long` has to be at least 64 bits wide and at least as wide as a `long`.

Note all those "at least"s. Each of those types can be wider than the minimum that's allowed, and when one of those types is wider it ripples through the rest of the types.

There are DSP chips out in the wild today that only address 32-bit values, so `char` is 32 bits wide, `short` is 32 bits wide, and `int` is 32 bits wide. That's an example of catering to the peculiarities of that hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Care is taken in the C++ standard not to restrict arithmetic types in such a way as to make them "unnatural" to any given hardware.  Most implementations, for example, use 2's complement integers and use IEEE Standard 754 for floating point numbers.  But they don't have to in order to be compliant with the standards. They could be 1's complement integers and not use IEEE Standard 754 for floating point types if that suited the hardware better and still be fully compliant with the C++ standard.

Comment: Note that signed integers are now required to be 2's compliment in both C and C++ upcoming standards. Also, C++ is generally a bit more strict  than C about its types and expectations.